# jqueryui portlets in column sorting

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am using jQuery UI [sortable portlets](http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/#portlets). The jqueryui sortable page refers to the documentation where you have event handlers attached if the portlets are moved from one column to the other, the recieve function takes care of the stuff, as shown below:

```
 $( ".column" ).sortable({
        connectWith: ".column",
        placeholder: 'ui-state-highlight',
        handle: 'h6',
        revert: true,
        receive: function(event, ui) {
         console.log(ui.item);
        }, 
         over: function(event, ui){
             console.log(ui.item);
        }
```

The `over` function as stated above, i thought would log if the element is moved up/down in the same column. But this does not happen.

So, how do i get an event when one portlet has been moved up/down within the same column.

A simple fiddle is [located here](http://jsfiddle.net/rUbQL/2/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to be looking for the [change](http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/#event-change) event, which is triggered when a sortable element's position is updated, even in the same column:

```
$(".column" ).sortable({
    connectWith: ".column",
    placeholder: "ui-state-highlight",
    handle: "h6",
    revert: true,
    receive: function(event, ui) {
        console.log(ui.item);
    },
    change: function(event, ui) {
        console.log(ui.item);
    }
});
```

You will find an updated fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/rUbQL/3/).

Answer (score 1):

The `sort` event seems to be equivalent to the `over` event, but within a column. The difference between `sort` and `change` is that `sort` fires as you move the element and `change` fires after you let go of the mouse and the element settles into its position.

```
sort : function (event, ui) {
    console.log(ui.item);
}
```

The events are well documented on the [jQuery UI pages](http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/#event-sort). Look through each of them to see which is most appropriate for your needs.

Comment: You don't actually have to release the mouse button for the `change` event to be triggered, only to move the element enough for its siblings to be reordered. On the other hand, in my tests, `sort` is triggered as soon as an element is moved, even if it keeps the same position (so it occurs *a lot*).

Answer (score 0):

The change function will do the trick.

```
$( ".selector" ).sortable({
   change: function(event, ui) { ... }
});
Bind to the change event by type: sortchange.
$( ".selector" ).bind( "sortchange", function(event, ui) {
  ...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

i've [forked](http://jsfiddle.net/pgeXS/23/) your snippet to work with your requirement
it only uses the change event for the purpose.

Here the trick is to keep track of the *column* of the portlet before an after the change. (Done through the `hasColumnChange` function)

The downside of using the change event is that it seems to fire twice, I don't know why, but nevertheless it should satisfy you.